# Longer Backtrace from CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS

Tags: macos, debugging, core-animation, backtrace

I'm tracking down a problem where CoreAnimation is finding that I'm deleting a thread with an uncommitted CATransaction.  This is probably a view animation group with a completion block.  As suggested by the NSLog message, I've set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS and I do indeed get an error message and a backtrace when this happens.

> CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction

Unfortunately, the backtrace goes back 15 levels, and none of these levels are particularly helpful. And almost all of them appear to be very common calls -- things like `CALayer needsDisplayInRect:` -- so setting a breakpoint doesn’t immediately suggest itself.

Is there a handy way to tell the system, "Live it up! Give me a deeper backtrace!" ?

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 10.0/macOS Sierra the limit has been increased to 512 stack frames.